# Why polarizations/ susceptibility needs to change to observe Raman Scattering?

Tags: solid-state-physics, raman-spectroscopy

When shining a crystal with light it will excite lattice vibrations or if you will, Phonons.

This has to fulfill the following conservation laws:

$\mathrm{k_s = k_i \pm q}$

$\mathrm{\omega_s = \omega_i \pm \omega_q}$

where $\mathrm{k_s}$ is the wave vector of the scattered light and $\mathrm{k_i}$ the wave vector of the incident light. $\mathrm{q}$ takes the role of the Phonon's wave vector.

For me this sounds like you can observe arbitrary shifts of $\mathrm{k_i}$ in the wave-vector-Intensity-spectrum caused by adding or subtracting some multiples of $\mathrm{q}$ to $\mathrm{k_i}$

However there exists this extra requirement of the polarization needing to change along the lattice vibration. But how is that? It doesn't appear in the conservation laws!